# syscall(SYS_getuid) returns different result from getuid()

Tags: c, windows, docker, system-calls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use syscalls to get the id of the current user. I tried it like this:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int uid = syscall(SYS_getuid);
    
    printf("%d\n", uid);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I executed it with root, but it prints `-1` instead of `0`.

If I replace it with `int uid = syscall(SYS_getuid);`, then it correctly returns `0`. What do I wrong? How to get the current user id using `syscall`?

I run it on `i686/ubuntu` docker image, because I have to create 32bit executables.

---

Minimal reproducible example:

Dockerfile

```
FROM i686/ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
        gcc libc6-dev
RUN apt-get clean all
```

main.c

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    int uid = syscall(SYS_getuid);//getuid();//
    
    if(uid == -1)
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    
    printf("%d\n", uid);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Run ( On x64 Windows10 ):

```
docker build --platform linux/386 -t my-gcc .
docker run --platform linux/386 --rm -v ${pwd}:/usr/local/src/:rw my-gcc gcc -m32 -xc /usr/local/src/main.c -o /usr/local/src/main
docker run --platform linux/386 --rm -v ${pwd}:/usr/local/src/:rw my-gcc /usr/local/src/main
```

The result is:

```
Error: Function not implemented
-1
```

Comment: `I run it on i686/ubuntu docker image.` Where, and how exactly did you compile it? As usuall - [MCVE]. What is your host architecture and system? `docker run -ti --rm i686/ubuntu` and then `apt-get update && apt-get install gcc && printf '%s\n' '#include <unistd.h>' '#include <sys/syscall.h>' '#include <stdio.h>' 'main() { printf("%d\n", syscall(SYS_getuid)); }' | gcc -m32 -xc - && ./a.out` works fine for me and returns `0`. Please create a full [MCVE].

Comment: @KamilCuk I provided a minimal example

Comment: *I would like to use syscalls to get the id of the current user.*  Why?  That's not [the standard way to get the current user's UID](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getuid.html), so you're not guaranteed to get the same results.  Note also that the standard `getuid()` function returns a `uid_t`, which is not necessarily an `int`.  What problem do you think using `syscall(SYS_getuid)` solves?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I would like to learn/practice using syscalls. Getting the user id seemed like a simple first exercise. I would like to understand, why this does not work and what is the difference

Comment: Can you print out the value of the `SYS_getuid` constant?  If this is a 32-bit Linux program, it ought to equal 24 as per https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#x86-32_bit.  If it is 102 instead then you are somehow including 64-bit headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [getuid(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html):

> The  original  Linux getuid() and geteuid() system calls supported only 16-bit user IDs.  Subsequently, Linux 2.4 added getuid32() and geteuid32(), supporting 32-bit IDs.  The glibc getuid() and geteuid() wrapper functions transparently deal with the variations across kernel versions.

Apparently you are running your program on a kernel that has the old `getuid` system call compiled out, and only `getuid32` is available on x86-32.  If you run `fgrep CONFIG_UID16 "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"`, you will be able to see if your running kernel supports the 16-bit syscall.  If this command prints anything other than [`CONFIG_UID16=y`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5f53fa508db098c9d372423a6dac31c8a5679cdf/init/Kconfig#L1463-L1468), it means the old system call is unavailable.

If you invoke `SYS_getuid32` instead, it should work fine.  Note that `SYS_getuid32` may fail to be available on other architectures.